# How to put interactive bokeh HTML image in Jupyterlab page

Tags: python, html, bokeh, jupyter-lab, voila

I'm using Jupyterlab (v 3.2.1) and bokeh to create a webpage that allows a user to load a .csv file containing a matrix, and a slider to optionally set a threshold on displayed results. The matrix contains simply some numerical values. The result would be an interactive heatmap displayed below the confirmation button. Whit my code the webpage is displayed correctly but the final plot is displayed in a new tab:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import jupyter_bokeh
import ipywidgets as widgets
import pandas as pd
import io
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColorBar, ColumnDataSource, CategoricalColorMapper
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import transform
import bokeh.palettes
from IPython.display import display, clear_output, display_html
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.embed import file_html
from bokeh.layouts import layout

#Display the webpage
file = widgets.FileUpload(accept=".txt, .csv, .dat", multiple=False)
threshold=widgets.IntSlider(value=0, min=0, max=20, step=1, description="Threshold:", disabled=False, continuous_update=False, orintation='horizontal', readout=True, readout_format="d")
button = widgets.Button(description='Run code')

text_0 = widgets.HTML(value="<header><h1>Phenotype Major Categories vs Genes Heatmap</h1></header>")
text_1 = widgets.HTML(value="<h3>Welcome to the heatmap plotter. By loading a csv file containing the counts of phenoypes for a gene into an IMPC major phenotype category, it will display an interactive heatmap.</h3>")
text_2 = widgets.HTML(value="Please load yor file (accepted formats: csv, txt, dat):")
text_3 = widgets.HTML(value="If desired, set a threshold for counts to be displayed:")
text_4 = widgets.HTML(value="<h2>Heatmap:</h2>")

vbox_head = widgets.VBox([text_0, text_1])
page_layout_plot = [text_2, file, text_3, threshold, button]
vbox_text = widgets.VBox(page_layout_plot)
page = widgets.VBox([vbox_head,vbox_text])
display(page)

#Set the endpage button to run the code
def on_button_clicked(result):
    #Load the file and set the threshold

    inp = list(file.value.values())[0] #if multiple setted to true, will not work!
    content = inp['content']
    content = io.StringIO(content.decode('utf-8'))
    mat = pd.read_csv(content, sep="\t", index_col=0)
    mat.index.name = 'MGI_id'
    mat.columns.name = 'phen_sys'

    #filtering phase
    rem=[]
    x = int(threshold.value)
    if x != 0:
        for i in mat.index:
            if mat.loc[i].max() < x:
                rem.append(i)
        mat.drop(rem,inplace=True,axis=0)

    #Create a custom palette and add a specific mapper to map color with values, we are converting them to strings to create a categorical color mapper to include only the
    #values that we have in the matrix and retrieve a better representation
    df = mat.stack(dropna=False).rename("value").reset_index()
    fact= df.value.unique()
    fact.sort()
    fact = fact.astype(str)
    df.value = df.value.astype(str)

    mapper = CategoricalColorMapper(palette=bokeh.palettes.inferno(len(df.value.unique())), factors= fact, nan_color = 'gray')

    #Define a figure
    p = figure(
        plot_width=1280,
        plot_height=800,
        x_range=list(df.phen_sys.drop_duplicates()[::-1]),
        y_range=list(df.MGI_id.drop_duplicates()),
        tooltips=[('Phenotype system','@phen_sys'),('Gene','@MGI_id'),('Phenotypes','@value')],
        x_axis_location="above",
        output_backend="webgl")

    #Create rectangles for heatmap
    p.rect(
        x="phen_sys",
        y="MGI_id",
        width=1,
        height=1,
        source=ColumnDataSource(df),
        fill_color=transform('value', mapper))
    p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 45

    #Add legend
    color_bar = ColorBar(
    color_mapper=mapper,
    label_standoff=6,
    border_line_color=None)
    p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')

    show(p)
    
button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```

I already tried to use `output_notebook()` at the beginning but in that case nothing is displayed.
How can I fix it? It would be useful to display in real time the plot by changing the threshold without the need to click the confirmation button every time.
Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to *observe* the value attribute of your `treshold` object to refresh your plot. So add something like this at the end of your code:

```
def on_value_change(change):
    on_button_clicked(None)

threshold.observe(on_value_change, names='value')
```

More from the doc: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Events.html#Signatures